# create a file and take out specific data

Tags: android, file, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am trying to create a file and save data to it and then I want to be able to read it and if its possible to take out specific data.

So here is my code to create and open a file.

```
public void createFile(View view) throws IOException {
    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    String string = "hello world";
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME,Context.MODE_APPEND);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();
}

public void openFile(View view) throws IOException{
    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    FileInputStream g = openFileInput(FILENAME);
    System.out.println(g.read());
    g.close();
}
```

Since the **read()** is returning an int and the value is a String that is stored one bit at a time if I understood correct.

Should parsing be an option?

Comment: you can check out this link for reference http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/fileinputstream_read.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently use these two methods to read and write to a file in android :

```
public String readFromInternalFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    String readData = ois.readObject().toString();


    return readData;
}



public void writeToInternalFile( String text, String fileName) {
    try  {
        OutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(text);
        fos.close();
        oos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

the second method will write your object to an internal file so not on the external storage and the first one is too read the object. Here I am reading the object as a String but this of course depends on the type of object you wrote to the file. You can replace the return method of the `readFromInternalFile` and make it `Object` and change the argument of the `writeToInternalFile` from `String text` to `Object objectToWrite` so you can easily read and write any object to a file with the same method.

So for universal read and write methods you will have :

```
public Object readFromInternalFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    Object readData = ois.readObject();


    return readData;
}



public void writeToInternalFile( Object objectToWrite, String fileName) {
    try  {
        OutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(objectToWrite);
        fos.close();
        oos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: I have set the Context.MODE_PRIVATE to MODE_APPEND because I want to add data to existing data. But this not seem to happen. Is there any looping that must be done?

Comment: @alexandermogren well in this case you are writing an object, so if you want to add something to an existing file what you need to do is first read the file, add the contents to the exitsing data then write it again.